# SharePoint 2010 Foundation Complete Install guide

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, installation

I could not find any guides on the net regarding complete installation of SharePoint 2010 Foundation on vm or SharePoint 2010 Foundation with AD on vm.

Here is my current progress:- 
1. I've setup a vm using VMware Player 
2. Installed Window Server 2008 R2 standard edition in that vm. 
3. Installed SQL Server 2008 R2 standard edition in that vm. 
4. Installed and configured AD. 
5. How do I proceed from here, I need some guide on how to do a complete install of the SharePoint 2010 Foundation so that I'm able to connect to the AD.

Please help me with some guidance or links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I don't need to configure anything for the SharePoint Foundation to connect to my AD. SPF will just pick up all the AD accounts. I completed my installation with the help from  [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470626380)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a test-AD in your installation, you need to set up another WM to host SharePoint. It is not recommended to install SharePoint on a domain controller, since domain controllers lacks stuff like "Local admin" security groups etc...

SharePoint setup instructions for a dev environment can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

And you can find good info on the Installation and Deployment Resource Center at MS: http://technet.microsoft.com/nb-no/sharepoint/ee518643.aspx

EndUserSharePoint.com also has a guide to set up a small farm using WMWare:
http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/06/09/how-to-install-sharepoint-2010-on-small-farm-part-1-full-installation-on-small-farm-up-to-managing-service-applications/

Alternatively can download the already configured Information Worker WM's from Microsoft:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27417

Instructions on converting them to WMWare can probably be found by the help of Google :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a step by step installation guide of SharePoint Foundation with screenshots here - http://wellytonian.com/2009/11/installation-sharepoint-2010-foundation-server/

Also here is a step by step installation guide of SharePoint Server 2010 with screenshots here from Fabian Williams which details about potential steps that needs to be taken for possible problems in the future - http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/how-to-installation-of-sharepoint-2010-in-a-small-farm-topology/