# Installing sharepoint 2010 foundation on windows 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, installation

Please tell me is there any potential issues for installing SharePoint 2010 Foundation on Windows 2008 R2 with SP1, or is it good to have SP2.

And let me know if anyone have a good tutorial for installing SP 2010 foundation.

Comment: Please find a similar post with 2010 Installation guide - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/sharepoint-2010-foundation-complete-install-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have SharePoint installed on several servers in our envirionment and all these servers are running Windows 2008 R2 with Service pack 1. We have encountered no exceptions regarding the OS. I am sure you could also google this though.